# How do I prevent user from going to a particular action through address bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How do I prevent users from going to a particular action through address bar.

for eg: in my rails app, If user type `localhost:3000/users/index` it shows the list of users.

How do I prevent this? and if anyone tries this I want them to be redirected into root page.

```
routes.rb

get 'signup' => 'users#new'
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
get 'blog' => 'user_posts#new'
resources :sessions
resources :user_posts
resources :users
```

Comment: please provide your `config/routes.rb` file

Comment: @AndreyKryachkov : edited.

Comment: Are you sure that you provided full `routes.rb` contents? As stated in Rails Guides, there should be no `/users/index` path available. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would normally be handled in the controller with a `before_action` callback, which will run before an action is triggered. Here's a simple way to implement it for the index action:

**users_controller.rb**

```
before_action :redirect_to_root, only: [:index]

# Controller actions...

private

def redirect_to_root
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Also, make sure you have a root path defined in your routes:

**routes.rb**

```
root 'some#action'
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `UsersController` you can add a `before_action` to ensure a user is logged in.

```
before_action :authorize_user!, only: :index

def authorize_user!
  redirect_to root_path unless session[:user_id].present?
end
```

If you never want access to the users index action then removing it from the generated routes is the best option.

```
get '/users', to: redirect('/')
resources :users, except: [:index]
```